# iOS UILocalNotification Sound

Tags: ios, iphone, uilocalnotification

Is there any way to play UILocalNotification Sound even if Sound is off. Actually I am trying to create an alarm which works even if user has turned off the sound. Or any alternative way to achieve this.

Answer (score 3):

If user has put the sound to off, there is no way for the app to play the sound. User settings always have the highest priorities than the applications.

Comment: And I sure hope it stays this way. Any other behaviour should be treated as a bug.

Comment: https://itunes.apple.com/gb/app/sleep-time-alarm-clock-sleep/id555564825?mt=8
Here is the application which does this, alarm sound is trigged even if sound is off.