# UILocalNotification with iPhone sound off

Tags: ios, iphone, settings, uilocalnotification

I need to play sound for UILocalNotification when iPhone sound off. Is it any way to achieve this or it is not possible?

Comment: I hope it's not possible. If I turn off the sound, that means I don't want to hear sound.

Comment: But default alarm clock is working, it is useful for reminders

Comment: What Apple can do and what you can do are different.

Answer (score 0):

No. Why should we have the ability to override the user's settings?

Related question: [iOS UILocalNotification Sound](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20717957/ios-uilocalnotification-sound)